# Android layout design..adjust on heading

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I want to implement tab in my application. Tab works well. Now implementing expandable list view in one of the tab... That means activity extends `Fragment` and not `FragmentActivity`... But I face a problem in expendable list view... How can I overcome this... Here is my code...

```
public class Setting extends Fragment{

    ExplistAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

      @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting, container, false);


            expListView = (ExpandableListView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();

            listAdapter = new ExplistAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            return rootView;

        }

    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("Remaining Battery");
        top250.add("Set Alarm Distance");
        top250.add("Pick Alarm Tone");
        top250.add("Set Vibrate");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("Remaining Battery");
        nowShowing.add("Set Alarm Distance");
        nowShowing.add("Pick Alarm Tone");
        nowShowing.add("Set Vibrate");


        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }


    }
```

error show on

```
listAdapter = new ExplistAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

Comment: What is the error? Post the logcat.

Comment: The constructor ExpandableListView(Setting, List<String>, HashMap<String,List<String>>) is undefined

Comment: Try using `getActivity();` instead of `this` keyword. Alternatively `getActivity().getAplicationContext();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `getActivity()` instead of this in your constructor. i suggest you to remove filling data into method `onActivityCreated()`. As `getActivity()` is ensured to return the activity creating the fragment only after getting this method called. And this is according to Android Developers docs link: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

So, remove your filling of data into `onActivityCreated()` and use `getActivity()` as the context passed to your adapter